# Unity. Help. Created a skiript for the enemy, in which hp decreases for all objects on which it hangs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a unity shooter. The task was to remove hp from each enemy in its own way.
My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class monster_animation : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject player;
public float dist;
NavMeshAgent nav;
public float Radius = 40f;
public static int health = 100;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (GameObject.Find("HitEffect(Clone)") != null)
    {
        health -= 25;
        Destroy(GameObject.Find("HitEffect(Clone)"));
    }

    dist = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);
    if(dist <= Radius)
    {
        if (dist <= 4)
        {
            nav.enabled = false;
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                nav.enabled = false;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("dead");

            }
            else
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("attack");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                nav.enabled = false;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("dead");
            }
            else
            {
                nav.enabled = true;
                nav.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
                gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("run");
            }

        }

    }
    if(dist > Radius)
    {
        nav.enabled = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("idle");
        
    }

}
}
```

Hang this script on different enemies, after hitting the hp should be taken from a specific enemy, not all.I tried to convert health to static - it didn't help. I made the private variable-it didn't help either. I searched for this answer on the Internet.

Comment: Don't check for hit (collisions) by searching a specific effect, otherwise, monster A could take the damages of monster B. You'd rather use [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) or [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is not the full code, I assume a few things. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
It seems like you create a HitEffect(Clone) when the bullet hits the enemy, right?
With this approach you the enemy does never know if the HitEffect which was created is next to it or to another player.
It would be easier to do this with physics. Please check on the [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) Function.
This function can be set eather to the enemy or the bullet, (I would do it to the bullet for Class based programming reasons) and check if the other part is a enemy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet_collision : MonoBehaviour
{
public int damage = 25;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
 monster_animation m = collision.GetComponent<monster_animation>();
 if (m != null)
 {
  m.health -= damage;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! The issue is resolved!